# Trimble coordinates in field not accurate

Tags: gps, trimble

I am using a Trimble Juno 3E and when I load the points taken in the field on GIS, it is off by a metre or so from the actual object (It doesnt fall on the exact object location). Any help to improve the accuracy please?

Comment: Accourding to this: http://www.datavaxt.se/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/022501-279H_Juno-3-Series_DS_A4_0815_LR.pdf it sounds like it is the best you can expect.

Comment: @BERA It can even be like 3-5 metres off from the actual object. Could it be something with the Terrasync setting on the GPS or what?

Comment: It says 2-5 meter real time and 1-3 m with post proccessing